# How can I avoid the exceptions of GlyphLayout in libgdx to get the width of a String at runtime?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using version 1.9.8 of libgdx. I use GlyphLayout to calculate the width of strings that I draw with BitmapFont, at runtime. I need the width to center the text in relation to a line drawn with a sprite.

```
private BitmapFont tickMarkFont;
private GlyphLayout tickGlyphLayout = new GlyphLayout();

tickMarkFont = manager.get("size16.ttf", BitmapFont.class);

private float getTickLabelSize(String text) {
        tickGlyphLayout.setText(tickMarkFont, text);
        return tickGlyphLayout.width;
}
```

However, I get multiple exceptions using this class. I get occasional crashes due to a null pointer exception on `setText`:

```
... java.lang.NullPointerException:
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.GlyphLayout.setText(GlyphLayout.java:141)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label.layout(Label.java:202)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Widget.validate(Widget.java:88)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table.layout(Table.java:785)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.WidgetGroup.validate(WidgetGroup.java:115)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button.draw(Button.java:198)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton.draw(TextButton.java:83)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.drawChildren(Group.java:110)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.draw(Group.java:57)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.drawChildren(Group.java:110)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.draw(Group.java:57)
at wall.mcv.actors.Scatterplot.draw(Scatterplot.java:379)
```

The same method also crashes sometimes due to `IllegalStateException: Array is empty`.

And the drawing also crashes sometimes:

```
tickMarkFont.draw(batch, tickGlyphLayout, x, y);
```

I am drawing the texts all the time and the crashes are just occassional, so it is hard to debug it.
I found a similar question: [(Libgdx 1.6.1) BitmapFontCache.draw crashing due to index out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618019/libgdx-1-6-1-bitmapfontcache-draw-crashing-due-to-index-out-of-bounds)

...but this doesn't help because my strings only have 1 line. They are usually numbers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use multi-threading?

Comment: Nope, I know ligbdx is not thread-safe. I use scene2D.

Comment: I'm looking at the source, and GlyphLayout line 141 should not be able to throw an NPE, because `GlyphRun.color` is a final member and `ReflectionPool.obtain` never returns a null object.